# Arrange itertools product in numerical order

Tags: python, tuples, python-itertools

I had a product done by itertools in the following way:

```
CHs=list(itertools.product(at_idx_map['H'], at_idx_map['C']))
```

obtaining the following output for CHs:

```
[(0, 1), (0, 6), (0, 11), (5, 1), (5, 6), (5, 11), (10, 1), (10, 6), (10, 11)]
```

however I would need arranged pairs in a numerical order, my desired output would be:

```
[(0, 1), (0, 6), (0, 11), (1,5), (5, 6), (5, 11), (1, 10), (6, 10), (10, 11)]
```

Does anyone have a suggestion for this:

Comment: How about the built-in `sorted()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Apply `sorted` on each item as you get it:

```
CHs=list(tuple(sorted(pair)) for pair in itertools.product(at_idx_map['H'], at_idx_map['C']))
```

Alternative:

```
CHs=list(map(tuple, map(sorted, itertools.product(at_idx_map['H'], at_idx_map['C']))))
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?